# Jquery sticky element in parent on bottom (fixed/absolute)

Tags: jquery, html, sticky

I'm trying to sticky an element on the bottom from the parent element, but i get some Problems .. 
what is the best solution for this, and especially the most resource-efficient (the sidebar and sticky element height can be changed at anytime, maybe)

image description:
http://oi44.tinypic.com/2ew2yj8.jpg

Thank you!

Comment: "but i get some Problems" Don't you think it would be better to explain which kind of issues you have? ... There are thousand of sample of responsive design, where are you stuck?

Comment: not sure what do you mean by saying, sticky at the bottom of parent. But all I can suggest is have position relative on parent and on the child, bottom:0

Comment: ok Problems are the wrong word, i don't know exactly how approach a problem.. is the calculation from the window size, sidebar and the sticky element on each scroll not to resource-intensive?

Comment: i have createt a short demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HpZ2S/

Comment: is this the correct way? or is there a better?